# Java protoc compiling issues

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-java

I am compiling proto file using command line mention below.

```
protoc -I ./ --python_out=. --grpc_out=. --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=`which grpc_python_plugin` ./test.proto
```

Above command i am issuing is to generate python based code and it works fine.

Now same command i tried to issue for Java based code but getting errors.

```
protoc -I ./ --java_out=. --grpc_out=. --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=`which grpc_java_plugin` ./test.proto
```

I looked at my plugin directory and found that following plug-ins are installed but not the Java one.

```
grpc_csharp_plugin
grpc_cpp_plugin
grpc_objective_c_plugin
grpc_node_plugin
grpc_python_plugin
grpc_ruby_plugin
```

How can i found the Java Plugin?

Comment: There is no java plugin, it is built into protoc use --java_out and remove the plugin parameter

Comment: by issuing protoc  -I=./ --java_out=. ./test.proto  i am able to generate files.

Comment: @BruceMartin Can you reply in answer field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin is hosted on Maven Central: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/grpc/protoc-gen-grpc-java/

While there isn't a protobuf plugin for Java (it is built into protoc), there is a plugin for the gRPC generated Stubs.  Normally this is provided for you by default as a Gradle plugin, but you can  manually download and use the plugin.  Currently, there are Linux, OSX and Windows builds.